# Iterate through json string in Observable angular js 2

Tags: angular

Following is my html code,

```
            <tr *ngFor="#c of content|async">           
                <td> {{c.name}}</td>
                <td>{{c.skill}}</td>
            </tr>
```

and in my json,

```
[{"name":"abc","skill":"xyz"}]
```

This is working but i need to iterate through this json string as,

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = obj[key];
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

this code is in javascript I want to do this in typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom pipe to return the list of key for each element.
Something like that:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
<tr *ngFor="#c of content | async">           
  <td *ngFor="#key of c | keys">{{key}}: {{c[key]}}</td>
</tr>
```