# How to ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have this set of data that i want to use in one of my ng2 projects:

```
{
  "Administration et gestion": [
    {
        "id": "1_1",
        "text": "Assistance comptable"
    },
    {
        "id": "1_2",
        "text": "Conseil fiscal et impots"
    },
    {
        "id": "1_3",
        "text": "Conseil juridique"
    },
    {
        "id": "1_4",
        "text": "Conseil auto-entrepreneur"
    }
  ],
  "Animaux": [
    {
        "id": "2_1",
        "text": "garde d'animaux"
    },
    {
        "id": "2_2",
        "text": "toitellage"
    }
  ],
  "Enfants": [
      {
          "id": "3_1",
          "text": "baby-sitting"
      },
      {
          "id": "3_2",
          "text": "aides au devoirs"
      }
  ],
}
```

Getting this data into ng1 was easy, I was doing something like this:

```
ng-repeat="(key, skill) in skills"
```

but angular2 doesn't support angular1 syntax, and solutions found don't work for me (some pipes). Rather that finding and pasting something randomly, can anyone help me to fully understand what I have to do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through json string in Observable angular js 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339411/iterate-through-json-string-in-observable-angular-js-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom pipe for this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
<div *ngFor="#keyValue of skills | keys">
  <div>{{keyValue.key}}<div>
  <div *ngFor="#value of keyValue.value">
    {{value.id}} = {{value.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add the pipe in the `pipes` attribute of your component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  pipes: [ KeysPipe ]
})
```

See this question for more details:

- [Invalid argument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881721/invalid-argument-for-pipe-asyncpipe/35885030#35885030)

Comment: hi thierry , thanks for you quick answer , so the pipe works well for the keyValue.key , but seems to not work for value.text or id, the number of item in keyvalue is right , but i have a blank item  please see http://prntscr.com/adfcot

Comment: Oh! There was a typo in my code: `<div *ngFor="#value if keyValue.value">` instead of `<div *ngFor="#value of keyValue.value">`. I updated my answer...

Comment: already corrected your typo , the number of item is correct but values are blank

Comment: Could you try `{{value | json}}` instead of `{{value.id}} = {{value.text}}` to see the content of the `value` object?

Comment: its also blank when i use `{{value | json}}`

Comment: I created a plunkr but I can't reproduce the problem. See this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/FkQcFE?p=preview.

Comment: Is the structure of data exactly the same than the provided one in your question?

Comment: yes the same
i used a skills service to get data 
`this.skills = this.http.get('json/skills.json').map(res =>   res.json());`
after i subscribe to the data , and display it

 ` getSkills(){
    this.Skillservice.skills.subscribe(skills => {
      skills = this.skills = skills;
      console.log(skills)
    })
  }
`

Comment: I updated my plunkr with an HTTP request but it seems to work... Could you fork this plunkr and put your code in it to see if it works and what are the differences?

Comment: Yes its work on plunker , but seems to not work in ionic2 
https://plnkr.co/edit/W6qmMlGNuVxVCUg2F2DS?p=preview

Comment: Really? That's strange...  Can you see array properties in your data when you do something like that: {{ skills | async }} ?

Comment: Oh great! What was the problem?

Comment: i was doing something wrong with ion-checkbox , thank you again