# Angular2 how to process service which is not array

Tags: angular

I have prepared service which looks the similiar to this:

```
            [{
                "Id": 1,
                "productName": "Cart",
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "productName": "Hammer",
            }]
```

I can use *ngFor in the view and go throught all items it works fine, but

1. Is there equivalent of *ngFor only if I have one item (not array)?:

   ```
   {
       "Id": 1,
       "productName": "Cart",
   }
   ```
2. In case of array I tryed to do this (it did not work):

   `<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;#last = last">`
       
      `<div *ngIF="#last">`
     
     `</div>`
     
   `</div>`

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  You could display properties one by one this way:

```
{{product.Id}} {{product.productName}}
```

If your data is loaded asynchronously, use the Elvis operator:

```
{{product?.Id}} {{product?.productName}}
```

You could iterate over the property names of the object using a custom pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let keyValue of product | keyValue">
 {{keyValue.key}} {{keyValue.value}}
</div>
```

See this question:

- [How to ngFor in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912660/how-to-ngfor-in-angular2/35912692#35912692)

2)  You could try the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let last = last">

   <div *ngIF="last">
  `
  </div>`
  `
</div>`
```

Comment: thank you, but I tried 1) but it did not work to me http://plnkr.co/edit/6hhz5Q?p=preview . I am probably missing something.

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps the Elvis operator is what you're looking for... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For # 1)
    you could just do

```
<div>{{item.value}}</div>
etc...
```

For # 2)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;>  
   <div *ngIF="(i == items.length -1)">  
  </div>  
</div>
```