# Angular 2 - displaying results after http request (Service)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to iterate my results in my `ngFor` - it's not so intuitive like Angular 1. I've the following:

**search.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor( private _http: Http ) {

  }

  DoGeneralSearch(s){   
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:6000/search?q=' + s)
     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  } 
}
```

**typeahead.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges} from "angular2/core";
import {SearchService} from "../../../services/search.service";

@Component({
  selector: "typeahead",
  providers: [SearchService],
  template : `
    <div>{{searchSvc | async | json}}</div>
    <div id="typeaheadRooms" *ngIf="searchSvc">
      <div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc?.rooms">
        <div class="typeaheadRoomTitle">{{item.name}}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc?.colors">
        <div class="typeaheadRoomTitle">{{item.name}}}</div>
      </div>
`,
})
export class TypeaheadComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() txt: string;
  display = false;

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    var search = changes['txt'].currentValue;
    if(search.length > 2) {
        this.display = true;
        this.searchSvc = this._searchService.DoGeneralSearch(search);
    }
    else
    {
        this.display = false;
    }
  }

  constructor(private _searchService: SearchService) {}
}
```

a typical results in json :

```
{  
"max":20,
"queryString":"chem",
"rooms":[  
  {  
     "name":"Lima"
  },
  {  
     "name":"Delta"
  }
 ],
"colors":[  
  {  
     "name":"Red"
  },
  {  
     "name":"Lime"
  }
 ]
```

}

What's happening ? Well, `{{searchSvc | async | json}}` show me results. 
But the `ngFor`: No :(

Any clues? thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through json string in Observable angular js 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339411/iterate-through-json-string-in-observable-angular-js-2)

Comment: No, Gunter...does not apply to my situation. But thanks because I bookmarked that post - Will be very useful in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use this:

```
<div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc | async">
```

and update your service like this:

```
DoGeneralSearch(s){   
  return this._http.get('http://localhost:6000/search?q=' + s)
     .map((res:Response) => res.json().rooms);
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to receive the full object from the observable, I see two ways to do that:

- Explicit subscribe:

  ```
  this._searchService.DoGeneralSearch(search).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.searchSvc = data;
    }
  );
  ```

  and in the template

  ```
  <div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc?.rooms">
  ```
- Custom pipe to get the `rooms` data:

  ```
  @Pipe({name: 'field'})
  export class FieldPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
      return value[args[0]];
    }
  }
  ```

  and in the template

  ```
  <div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc | async | field:rooms">
  ```

Comment: Hi again, Therry ;) Well..I edited the result...it can return rooms or colors in fact. if I set this on the service..I will restrict myself just to grab the rooms array :( Just for curious I set in this fashion to test your async on the ngFor and it's works..but I really need to iterate in different keys....

Comment: Almost there ! I just added: import "Pipe, PipeTransform} from "angular2/core" , @ component....pipes: [FieldPipe]....@ pipe(....) , @ export class FieldPipe (....) and this still throw me a No Directive annotation found on TypeaheadComponent - Something missing ?

Comment: It seems that a `@Component` annotation is missing on your `TypeaheadComponent` component... Could you give me the corresponding code?

Comment: sure ! [typeahead]: import {FieldPipe} from '../../_generics/field-pipe.component';______ @Component({
  selector: "typeahead",
  providers: [SearchService],
  pipes: [FieldPipe]...
template : `<div class="typeaheadRowRooms" *ngFor="#item of searchSvc | async | field:rooms"><div class="typeaheadRoomTitle">{{item.name}}</div></div>` ____ export class TypeaheadComponent (...) this.searchSvc = this._searchService.DoGeneralSearch(search).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                    this.searchSvc = data;
                }
            ); [field-pipe-component] : import and @pipe and expor

Comment: I placed your pipe in a different file now...now it's throw me EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [searchSvc | async | field:rooms in TypeaheadComponent@15:43]

Comment: nvmd ! I reviewd !! now it's working !! get another "Answered" from me ! U r a star, Thierry !